# Weird OutOfMemoryError from JBoss AS 7.2

Tags: osgi, jboss7.x

I'm experiencing an odd `OutOfMemoryError` when deploying OSGi/Blueprint bundles in JBoss AS 7.2. Some of my bundles cause this error if they are present in the deployment directory when I start JBoss - but only in combination with each other.

In my current setup I have four bundles - let's call them `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. `A` and `B` depends on `C` and `D` but not on each other, and they all use various external libraries which I have also deployed. If `C` and `D` are deployed with exactly one of `A` and `B` when JBoss starts, everything seems to deploy fine, but if both `A` and `B` are present I get the following stack trace:

```
16:42:30 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jbosgi.PersistentBundles.RESOLVE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jbosgi.PersistentBundles.RESOLVE: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1939) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:335) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.mergeUses(ResolverImpl.java:911)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.mergeUses(ResolverImpl.java:957)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.mergeUses(ResolverImpl.java:957)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.calculatePackageSpaces(ResolverImpl.java:696)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:188)
        at org.jboss.osgi.resolver.felix.StatelessResolver.resolve(StatelessResolver.java:56)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.ResolverImpl.resolveAndApply(ResolverImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.internal.PackageAdminImpl.resolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:366)
        at org.jboss.osgi.framework.spi.BootstrapBundlesResolve.start(BootstrapBundlesResolve.java:127)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA.jar:1.0.4.GA]
        ... 3 more

16:42:30 ERROR [stderr] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(LinkedList.java:667)
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:284)
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at java.util.AbstractSequentialList.iterator(AbstractSequentialList.java:222)
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$ServerTimerTask.run(ServerImpl.java:849)
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
16:42:30 ERROR [stderr]         at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

and a little later

```
16:42:40 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jbosgi.PersistentBundles.COMPLETE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."com.springsource.org.jgroups-2.2.8.jar".CONFIGURE_MODULE, service jboss.deployment.unit."com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar".CONFIGURE_MODULE, service jboss.deployment.unit."com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm-1.5.3.jar".CONFIGURE_MODULE, service jboss.deployment.unit."com.springsource.org.hibernate-3.3.1.GA.jar".CONFIGURE_MODULE, JBAS014799: ... and 54 more ]
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jbosgi.PersistentBundles.RESOLVE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jbosgi.PersistentBundles.RESOLVE: Failed to start service
```

(all the libraries listed here are previously listed as deployed successfully, although I haven't been able to check wich the "54 more" are, and if they're all present)

I'm completely at a loss here. What could cause this behavior? Where do I start troubleshooting?

Comment: Did you try to increase the amount of memory of the process?

Comment: @PeterKriens: Yes, I did (and of course I should have said so), but it didn't help.

Comment: @PeterKriens: Also, the error mysteriously disappears if I *first* start JBoss, without these libraries deployed, and then move them into the deployment directory. In other words, this doesn't work: 1) put all the bundles in the deployments dir 2) start jboss; but this works: 1) start jboss with only `C` and `D` in the deployment dir, and wait for startup phase to finish 2) deploy `A` and `B`.

Comment: It sounds like you're running in a resolver bug. Could you try to resolve those bundles in Apache Felix?